# Jquery Calendar arrows missing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I was trying out the Jquery Calendar on my website and it worked fine. I linked the css stylesheet from ajax.googleapis.com and the calendar was fine but too big. So i simply copied the file to my server and changed the height and the width in the file.

But now the arrows for moving forward and backward have gone. How do I get them back while hosting the css on my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to also host the image files on your server (or fix up the url's in the downloaded stylesheet)

If you download jQuery UI from the website, you'll get all the required files included.

Comment: I actually have all the ui-icons_*.png files in an images folder. Still the arrows wont show up.

Comment: @Ali: well you still need to have them in the right place. it expects an *images* folder in the folder where your css file is, unless you've tampered with the css file. in the developer tools of your browser, you can see what images are being requested, find the 404 ones, and look at exactly what url they're at.

Comment: While I already had the images folder and the images in place, i forgot to read that Jquery generates unique icons names for each download. I was thus using the old names in my new jquery-css file. Thanks.